# Adding Controls to a Container within a Structure Declaration in VB .NET

Tags: vb.net, data-structures, panel, containers, parent-child

Is there any way of adding a control to a container within a structure declaration in VB .NET?

What I would really like to do is:

```
Structure LabelContainer
    Dim pnlContainer As New Panel
    Dim lblTime As New Label
    Dim lblStudent As New Label
    Dim lblTeacher As New Label
    lblTime.Parent = pnlContainer
    lblStudent.Parent = pnlContainer
    lblTeacher.Parent = pnlContainer
End Structure
```

But this doesn't work in VB .NET. Is there anyway of achieving the same thing?

Comment: You can't put code in a structure declaration.  Use a class, put the code in the constructor.  And pick up a book about vb.net programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Structures have very limited handling of the events required by controls, such as the InitializeComponent() event that is fired when a control is created. See this for more details:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8607/Using-Structures-in-VB-NET

What you could do is create a class that inherits from a panel instead, for example:

```
Public Class LabelContainer
    Inherits Panel
    Friend WithEvents lblTeacher As System.Windows.Forms.Label
    Friend WithEvents lblStudent As System.Windows.Forms.Label
    Friend WithEvents lblTime As System.Windows.Forms.Label

    Private Sub InitializeComponent()
        Me.lblTime = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
        Me.lblStudent = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
        Me.lblTeacher = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
        Me.SuspendLayout()
        '
        'lblTime
        '
        Me.lblTime.AutoSize = True
        Me.lblTime.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(0, 0)
        Me.lblTime.Name = "lblTime"
        Me.lblTime.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(100, 23)
        Me.lblTime.TabIndex = 0
        Me.lblTime.Text = "Label1"
        '
        'lblStudent
        '
        Me.lblStudent.AutoSize = True
        Me.lblStudent.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(0, 0)
        Me.lblStudent.Name = "lblStudent"
        Me.lblStudent.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(100, 23)
        Me.lblStudent.TabIndex = 0
        Me.lblStudent.Text = "Label2"
        '
        'lblTeacher
        '
        Me.lblTeacher.AutoSize = True
        Me.lblTeacher.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(0, 0)
        Me.lblTeacher.Name = "lblTeacher"
        Me.lblTeacher.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(100, 23)
        Me.lblTeacher.TabIndex = 0
        Me.lblTeacher.Text = "Label3"
        Me.ResumeLayout(False)

    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a sub to your Struct:

```
Structure LabelContainer
    Dim pnlContainer As Panel
    Dim lblTime As Label
    Dim lblStudent As Label
    Dim lblTeacher As Label
    Sub AddControls()
        lblTime.Parent = pnlContainer
        lblStudent.Parent = pnlContainer
        lblTeacher.Parent = pnlContainer
    End Sub
End Structure
```